# 2sxc 13 - Get username and other DNN tokens in formulas/calculations

Tags: dotnetnuke, 2sxc

Is there a way to get the current username in a formula (the v1(data, context) new stuff)? And other DNN tokens as we would on a view.

Current date is easier, since it dependends only on c#, but I can't any documentations for username.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with Razor templates, yiu can call and and all DNN methods.  Also, while editing a template, the dark left column of the edit screen gives you access to all sorts of snippets that you can use by clicking on them.

Comment: This is for the formulas new feature, not the template design.

Answer (score 0):

This feature is still experimental and doesn't do much outside of its context in the browser. We've done a few tests and could not reach outside the Angular app's scope (which makes sense). I do believe there are plans wire up things like that. Daniel will probably chime in.

In the mean time, there is no reason you can't write your own API to get the answers you need from the backend. The formulas aren't limited in any way, so there is no reason not to do it like this (assuming writing your own C# 2sxc WebApi code is something you are familiar with):

```
async function api()
{
  let tmp = await sxc.webApi.fetchJson('/api/2sxc/app/myapp/api/score/progress');
  console.log(JSON.stringify(tmp));
}
```

Comment: I apologize, but I really do not understand how this would be implemented or how this would return the username. I have created custom APIs before withing the 2sxc apps, but nothing like this.

Comment: It was just an example showing how you can get data from the backend in your formula's JS. You'd have to write your own webapi and figure out how to identify the user and return the username (which is easy in C#, but in the webapi I don't think you have session context, so no user? not sure).  It does seem like too much work to me.. Maybe, instead, it would be a good idea to post this as an issue in 2sxc and present your need and use-case. Since I expect Formulas to get fleshed out quite a bit this year, getting you needs stated well might help get solutions in place that don't exist yet.

Answer (score 0):

Just fyi: 2sxc 13.10.02 will have a `context.sxc` which is great for calling APIs, as well as a `context.user.id` which will give you some user info. Using this you should be able to get this to work.

Comment: Daniel, this is great, but where are they documented? Am I able to get the user's username or email address yet? If yes, will this just automatically work the same in Oqtane? https://docs.2sxc.org/js-code/2sxc-api/index.html

Comment: I suggest you start with https://docs.2sxc.org/basics/edit/formulas/index.html

Comment: We also finally got to document the $2sxc/sxc APIs directly from the code - it's not complete yet, but you can find what we have here https://docs.2sxc.org/api/js/home.html and much more here: https://docs.2sxc.org/js-code/index.html